# How to read csv file with a column containing commas in its field?

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file of comma seperated data about movies. Unfortunately some of the entries of the column 'movies name' contain comma . So when I read the file in R using comma as seperator, it is creating problem. But one thing to mention is that the commas in movies name column are always preceded by \ . Is there a way to use these back slashes to prevent read.csv function from using these commas in movies name for seperating?

Comment: Can you replace "\," with something else outside of R?

Comment: I was asked not to make any changes in csv. file  but try to deal with the problem using R.

Comment: Can you show first few rows of your csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following data in a csv file

```
id,movie_name
1,a\,b\,c
2,ab\,bc\,cd
```

You could do this by reading the lines of the data as a vector of strings, replacing "\," with something else and then reading it as csv

```
> read.csv(text=gsub("\\\\,","_",readLines("mycsv.csv")))
  id movie_name
1  1      a_b_c
2  2   ab_bc_cd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use allow escape option in read.csv. Assuming that movie column is a  quoted string.
I have used the below data for verification:

```
#Assumed csv file
Id,Movie_Name
1,"ab\,bc\,cd"
2,"abcd\,bc\,cd"
 
read.csv("<file path>",header = T,allowEscapes = T)
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the column value must be surrounded by quotes, otherwise won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the mention. @user2974951 I have updated my answer accordingly.